# How to save all tabs in a FireFox window?

Tags: firefox-extensions

Sometimes when I'm researching on a software issue (i.e. a bug that I most likely created), I google a lot and so have a lot of tabs open in FireFox. I don't use IE :)

But FireFox only allows me to save the open-tabs for the *last session*.
Is there a way that I can sort of *command* FireFox to obey => *for this FireFox main window containing all these open tabs, save the session as name "researching on bug #232 -- file is not saving"* so that I can come back later and click on a button to have all those tabs open up again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is extension for that [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/2324/).

Comment: Session Manager is a must have FireFox addon... Others are FireBug, Tab Mix Plus, and All-In-One Sidebar.

Comment: I loved Session Manager (despite a few oddities)!... until I realized it was crashing my browser and/or causing insane levels of memory usage. :( I'm hoping the stability improves, or someone takes the idea and builds on it with a more stable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Either use session manager (which can also fail in my personal experience) or save all the tabs as bookmarks in a separate folder.

To achieve the latter, right click any tab and select "bookmark all tabs" and type in a folder name at the prompt

Comment: or access it via Bookmarks on the menu bar